# Undefined function 'select' for input arguments of type 'database.jdbc.connection'

Tags: matlab, jdbc, h2

I am creating database connection with method of

```
>> conn = database('MYDB','','','org.h2.Driver','jdbc:h2:file:mypath')
```

and this command apparently works. Then I try to

```
>> selectquery = 'SELECT * FROM IMAGE';
>> data = select(conn,selectquery);
```

and this fails with

> Undefined function 'select' for input arguments of type
>   'database.jdbc.connection'.

Why? What does it want? How to select from JDBC database in Matlab?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the database toolbox? Can you show the value of `con`?

Answer (score 0):

there is not a select function to work with database in matlab

you must execute a sql query with exec function

for example :

```
y=exec(conn,your_query);
```

or

```
selectquery = 'SELECT * FROM IMAGE';
data = exec(conn,selectquery);
```